# Hide a div to subscribers(user role) in one page (is_page)

Tags: php

Hello have been looking at this for quite a while and cant seem to resolve it was hoping someone more familiar with the wordpress core and php could share some idea.

What I want to accomplish essentially is to Hide a div that permits buddypress users (the subscrivers) from adding new topics to a group forum. But I dont want this to be hidden from all the forums just 1 of them. So I need 2 pieces 1 that determines whether someone is a subscriber or an admin. so its only hidden to the subscriber. and 2 that it hides it from only 1 page.

Example of potential code just need to fit it together (all code would go in the functions.php unless there is another way)

```
<?php /* If this is the frontpage */ if ( is_home() || is_page() ) { ?>
have info link or whatever in here
<?php } ?>
```

Thats for the frontpage but similarly you can get the page by ID

For role I saw this

```
is_admin()
```

I would assume there is a

```
is_subscriber()
```

and from there you can do an if in the php something like
  if is_subscriber() and is_page( 42 )
call .js file and from there add a class that hides the div I want to hide by jquery

Thats as far as I got from what I know and looking around. I would greatly appreciate any and all assistance.

Comment: FYI, [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) checks for whether the user is on the Dashboard or administration panel, not whether the user is the adminastrator of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Just hiding a div is insecure - they can easily unhide it by editing the source or executing some Javascript in the browser's URL bar.
I believe this may be what you're looking for:

```
<?php
if (current_user_can(‘subscriber’)){
?>

[html here]

<?php
}
?>
```

Source: [How to Use WordPress to Display Content Depending on a User’s Level](http://wplifeguard.com/how-to-use-wordpress-to-display-content-depending-on-a-users-level/)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the ID of the page you want to hide the button on, you can use `is_page()` in the loop. Outside of the loop, use this:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
```

While @JamesF's answer should work, using roles is considered to be less-stable than testing against a specific capability. You can find [a table comparing roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) on the Codex. The only capability subscribers have is `read`, so you'd test against that.

Your final code, would then look like this:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
if( $post_id = 42 && current_user_can( 'read' ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The final step is where to put this. Unless you're programmatically adding the button via functions.php, you'll be looking to wrap the button (aka "`// do stuff`") in the above code in an existing theme file. That will require tracking down the button in your theme, or possibly finding where it's made via a PHP function in BuddyPress.